# Asynchonous subtasks in Celery Python

Tags: python, celery

i need async call subtasks in celery to another worker (on another machine) like this:

```
#db.py
@task()
def query(x,y):
   ...something
   return z

#worker2.py
@task()
def main(x,y):
   result=db.query.async((x,y), queue='db')
   try:
       a=result.get(timeout=5)
   except celery.exceptions.TimeoutError:
       ....
```

But i get warning when starting worker:
**RuntimeWarning: Never call result.get() within a task!**

How can i call async tasks from another task? I wont'n use chain, chord etc.

Comment: The correct approach is to use chain. Why can't you use it?

Comment: I tried chain now:
    res = chain(db.query.s(x, y))()
    print(res.get())
and i get ** Never call result.get() within a task!** again :(

Comment: Same question here. Celery plays nice with fixed scenarios where you know from the start what will be executed, but when the scenario is dynamic I've got this issue & it blocks a worker

Answer (score 1):

You never want to block one task to wait for another, so the correct approach is to use [chain](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains):

```
db.py
@task()
def query(x, y):
   ...something
   return z

#worker2.py
@task()
def main(resultFromQuery, x, y):
   a = resultFromQuery.get(timeout=5)
   ...

res = chain(query.s(x,y), main.s(x,y));
res.get()
```

Comment: but i need call subtask from another task. Not from Main program.
This is system where i don't kwow exact workflow of at the begin :(

Comment: then don't call `result.get()` - do you need the result of the second task ?